# How to Make String Type Become Array Type

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I have input field that i fill array when i dump that array become string type.

my input on field :
['name'=>'juned']

Condition :

```
$value = "array()";
```

Expected Output :

```
$value = array();
```

I want to fill input with array type and get it as array type again.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Please rephrase the question, it's unclear what is your goal.

Comment: If you are talking about a text input field then whatever you put there is a string. How you format it doesn't really matter. It is always transmitted to PHP as a string and this is how PHP treats it. If you want to transform the data to an array I would suggest using JSON and `json_decode` to convert it to array.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```
if ($value == "array()")
    $value = array();
```